# Fetch polyfill for pure javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, polyfills

I have a Javascript file where code is written in Javascript ES6 standards.The file is working fine in chrome but its not working in IE. After doing logs, I found out issue is in making ajax calls. Following code is where I am trying to make calls:

```
var response = await fetch(url, xhrRequestObject);
        if (response.ok) {
            var jsonResponse = await response.json();
            return jsonResponse;
        }
```

I googled through and found some polyfills to rectify this issue.But I am not getting how to use these polyfills inpure javascript file.

Any suggestions on how to use these polyfills in a pure js file ?

Comment: don't. use https://babeljs.io

Comment: Being picky wasn’t await introduced in ECMAScript2017 (ES8) not ES6?

Answer (score 4):

I can't believe I didn't mention using Babel, see [Marcel Gerber's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53360880/157247) for more on that.

But if you don't want to transpile:

---

Any `fetch` polyfill will have to provide or rely on a `Promise` polyfill. Then, since you're targeting IE, you can't use `async` functions and the `await` keyword because they were added in ES2018 and aren't supported by any version of IE.

So instead, you'd have to use promise syntax instead of `await`:

```
fetch(url, xhrRequestObject).
.then(function(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error, status = " + response.status);
    }
    return reponse.json();
})
.then(function(data) {
    // ...use `data` here, it's the result of parsing the JSON
})
.catch(function(error) {
    // ...handle error here...
});
```

Or if you're returning this to a caller (your code suggests you might be):

```
return fetch(url, xhrRequestObject).
.then(function(response) {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error, status = " + response.status);
    }
    return reponse.json();
});
```

Note that the caller would need to handle errors on the promise that returns.

Comment: Fetch is not supported either in IE. So is there any way to use fetch polyfill in a pure js file to make fetch work in IE ?

Comment: @nip_sham - Yes, I referred to using a polyfill above. There are at least a couple of polyfills for `fetch`: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=fetch+polyfill

Comment: @t.jcrowder I am not getting how to use these polyfills in my pure js file

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to polyfill new syntax features, like the "await" keyword you're using here.

Instead, your best bet is to use a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). A transpiler takes your *modern* code and tries to make it executable in older browser versions. I'm not sure whether Babel supports async/await and if the transpiled code is executable in IE, though.